# Homomorphic hash from prime order group $G$ to $Z_p$

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, homomorphic-signatures

Let $G$ be a cyclic group with the generator $g$ and of prime order $p$ such that the discrete-logarithm problem is hard in $G$.

A hash function is homomorphic if $H(a\ast b)=H(a)\cdot H(b)$ (where the operations $\ast$ and $\cdot$ depend on the groups). Here we do not expect the hash function to be compressing, but collision-resistance (CR) and efficiently computeable.

Now the question is, if there exist  such homomorphic hash function from group $G$ to $Z^+_p$?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{Z}_p^+$ or $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$?  Note that $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ has order $p-1$...

Comment: What do you mean by a "hash"? You haven't stated any target security properties, and $H$ does not seem to have to be compressing.

Comment: I added the details on the security requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The function is usually referred to as the discrete logarithm function. It is defined by
$$H:G\to(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^+$$
$$H(g^X)=X$$

The function always exists, but if $G$ is a cryptographic group, then $H$ should be infeasible to compute. Technically, there is one such function for every $g$, but they are all multiples of each other.

We would typically just call this a function rather than a hash function. It's certainly not a cryptographic hash function as it can be inverted with $O(\log p)$ operations in $G$.

ETA: Note that by the homomorphic property $H(h^a)=aH(h)$ and so the value of $H(g)$ completely determines the function. In other words the discrete logarithm function and its multiples represent *all* possible homomorphic functions from $G$ to $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^+$. There are no others.

Comment: The function is injective, hence it is in particular (perfectly) collision-resistant (in the sense that collisions do not even exist). Therefore, I guess you should perhaps rethink a bit what you are looking for exactly. In particular, you might also want $H$ to be efficient (here, evaluating $H$ requires computing a discrete logarithm, for which we don't have a general polytime algorithm)

Comment: Sorry. yes, being efficiently computable is a trivial property I had in mind, and also pre-image resistance.